# Accessing activity from another project in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

From my android application, I want to access one activity which is a part of another project. For that i linked that project with my application and i've declared that activity inside my manifest. But still not working. Logcat shows,

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.apptwo
```

manifest declaration:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.apptwo.Activity2"></activity>
```

starting the activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, com.example.apptwo.Activity2.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Can anyone help me.....?

Comment: What do you mean by access? start?

Comment: You'd probably need to add the other project as a library. Or better yet, have the components that you're trying to access in a library that both projects try to access.

Comment: @dtmilano: yes, to start that activity.....

Comment: first you need to make sure apptwo is a library project for which your app project is using. And then you have to declare that activity in your app project's manifest. NOT apptwo's manifest.

Comment: @user123 : post your code where u are starting Activity2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need to add any class in your project's `Manifest` which won't exists in it.

To access an `Activity` which is either from any other project or so. You just need to pass the whole Class name including it package name when you are using it in `Intents` or so.

Added:- It worked, but the activity in the library should have to be declare in the manifest file.

Comment: I've tried it....but got this exception...........android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.appone/com.example.apptwo}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: it worked....but the activity in the library should be declared in the manifest file.....

Answer (score 0):

If you have added that project as Library project, then there is no need to define it inside the `Manifest`. You just have to access it by importing it in Java class.

```
import com.example.apptwo.Activity2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code in your java file in which you have to access the activity from the other project.

```
 import com.example.apptwo.Activity2;
```

And then by importing that you can access the methods and variables from that activity.Use intents to move from the first to second activity.

Answer (score -1):

Use the intent and set the component name using Strings:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.apptwo", "com.example.apptwo.Activity2");
startActivity(intent);
```

If "com.example.apptwo" is installed and Activity2 is exported in its manifest it will work.

Comment: BTW, you don't have to include anything or link your projects to do that

Comment: So this should only work if the second app is already installed in the device...right?